# ¿como soluciono Notice: Undefined index?

Tags: php

queria saber si hay alguna solucion en mi codigo, ya que cuando lo ejecuto me salta el error de Undefined Index... a continuacion les dejo mi codigo, respondan porfavor.

```
<HEAD>
   <TITLE>Conversor de monedas</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<H1>Conversor de monedas</H1>

<?PHP
$enviar = $_REQUEST['enviar'];
   if (isset($enviar))
{
      $tablaconversion = array (
      "dolar" => 0.0124,
      "euros"  => 0.0104,
      "chilenos"   => 9.59,
      "reales"   => 0.0666,
      "guaranies"   => 87.17
      );
   $pesosarg = $_REQUEST['pesosarg'];
   $moneda = $_REQUEST['moneda'];
   if ($pesosarg == "")
      print ("<P>Debe introducir una cantidad</P>\n");
   else
   {
      $cantidad = $pesosarg * $tablaconversion ["$moneda"];
      print ("<P>$pesosarg Peso(s) equivale(n) a $cantidad $moneda</P>\n");
   }

      print ("<P>[ <A HREF='javascript:history.back()'>Volver</A> ]</P>\n");
   }
   else
   {
?>
```

el error que me sale es en la linea 12, es decir en esta `$enviar = $_REQUEST['enviar'];` la que sale en el principio...

Comment: Estás primero asignando algo y luego comprobando si existe... prueba a hacerlo al revés, comprueba `isset($_REQUEST['enviar'])` y luego trabaja con él ya

Comment: Intente hacer lo que me recomendaste y funciono, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Debes comprobar si el indice existe en el array, no si existe la variable a la que tratas de asignarle el contenido:

```
<?php
$enviar = isset($_REQUEST['enviar']) ? $_REQUEST['enviar'] : null;
if ($enviar) {
    
    // tu código

} else {
    echo 'no existe el indice "enviar" en $_REQUEST';
}
```

La línea:

```
$enviar = isset($_REQUEST['enviar']) ? $_REQUEST['enviar'] : null;
```

es un *ternario*, equivale a:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['enviar'])) {
    $enviar = $_REQUEST['enviar'];
} else {
    $enviar = null;
}
```

EN principio `$_REQUEST` es una *superglobal* y debe existir aunque sea como array vacío. Puedes ver su contenido con:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Cuando tienes un array, si no sabes si un indice concreto existe, esta sería la comprobación mínima antes de tratar de acceder a ese indice:

```
if (isset($arr['indice'])) {
    // ...
}
```

y si no sabes si ese array existe en ese punto del programa:

```
if ($arr && isset($arr['indice'])) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Si metes un ternario en una respuesta a alguien que está empezando en programación, lo mínimo que deberías hacer es explicarle ***QUE ES*** un operador ternario y qué hace. Aunque directamente te diría que usar un operador ternario en una respuesta a alguien que no tiene muchos conocimientos es mala idea, lo mejor sería usar una estructura `if else` básica para facilitar la lectura y comprensión del código por parte de todos :)